# Sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ convergent implies Cauchy, but not vice versa?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Earlier I proved that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ converges to some limit $\vec{a}$ if and only if it is Cauchy. Now, I've also proved that if the sequence $\{\vec{x}_k\}$ is convergent to some limit $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\|\vec{x}_k - \vec{x}_{k+1} \| = 0$. I proved it in the following way: since $\{\vec{x}_k\}$ is convergent, it is Cauchy, which implies that, $\forall\varepsilon >0, \exists K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|\vec{x}_k-\vec{x}_l\|<\varepsilon$ whenever $k,l\ge K$. Let $k>K,l=k+1$, then $k+1>K$ and $\|\vec{x}_k-\vec{x}_{k+1}\|<\varepsilon$, which implies that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\|\vec{x}_k - \vec{x}_{k+1} \| = 0$ by definition of the limit at infinity.

Now, the next question I have to solve seems to contradict the above. Namely, the question asks me to provide a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$) to show that the converse of the statement above is not true. Because how can it be not true if Cauchy implies convergence?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ Cauchy implies convergency because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a complete metric space.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez I will clarify this in my original question: an example has to be in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, Cauchy implies convergent, so in order to find a counterexample to Cauchy implies convergent you will have to work in some other space. You don't have to get too exotic; there is a space quite similar (in certain respects) to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that will work.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ consider the sequence $x_n=\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$. It is Cauchy but not converges. The problem here is because $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not complete.

Comment: The confusing thing is that it is said that "it is okay to provide an example in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$". $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ appears to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but not $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: Because the Completeness of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$), you can't find a counterexample of Cauchy sequence such that not converges.

Comment: The statement wasn't convergence implies cauchy.  It was convergence implies difference of adjancent terms converge.  SO the converse counter example is not find a cauchy sequence that doesn't converge (which is impossible) but find a sequence whose difference of adjacent terms converges but the sequence does not.  *cough* *cough* harmonic *cough*

Comment: @fleablood But adjacent terms satisfy the Cauchy condition, don't they?

Comment: No!  They absolutely do *not*!.

Comment: Cauchy means for any $e>0$ there is an $M$ so that for *ALL* $n, m > M$ then $|a_n + a_m| < e$.  $a_n$ and the imediately adjacent term $a_{n+1}$ are not *ALL* $n, m > M$.  There is one *very* famous counter example.

Comment: see $|a_n - a_{n+1}|$ can be very very small but $|a_n - a_{n + 10^{100}}|$ can be *huge*.  (well it can't be bigger than one googol times epsilon but that is big).  |a_n - a_m| need not be bounded at all

Comment: @fleablood Now I seem to get it, thanks.

Comment: @fleablood However, since the limit goes to infinity, doesn't this mean that sooner or later $n$ and $n+1$ will necessarily be greater than any $M>0$, which will satisfy the Cauchy condition?

Comment: Nope.  You get the difference of terms getting smaller but the difference the *sum* of the difference don't need to converge.  Suppose a_1 = 1 and a_2 = 1 + 1/2 and a_n = 1 + 1/2 + ..... + 1/n.  Then a_n+1 - a_n = 1/(n+1) and that converges to 0.  But a_m - a_n = 1/m + 1/(m-1) + 1/(m-2) + ........ + 1/n+1.  That is not convergent at all and indeed we can pick an M,  and an m where a_n+1 - a_n < e for all n > M but for that n we can pick an m > n and any N  so that a_m - a_n > N.

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)  It is the *classic* counter example.  The difference between any two terms converges to zero but the sequence itself does not.

Comment: @fleablood Now I get the subtlety. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Because how can it be not true if Cauchy implies convergence?*"

Because your counter-example will not/can not be Cauchy.

$\{a_n\}$ being Cauchy/convergent implies $|a_n - a_{n+1}|$ converges to $0$ but $|a_n - a_{n+1}|$ converging to $0$ does  not imply $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy/convergent.

And that is what you must find a counter example of: $\{a_n\}$ being such that $|a_n - a_{n+1}|$ converges to $0$ but $\{a_n\}$ is not Cauchy/convergent.

======= counter example below ======

Let $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i$. Then $a_n$ does not converge but $|a_n - a_{n+1}| = \frac 1{n+1} \rightarrow 0$.

Cauchy is *all* $|a_n - a_m| \rightarrow 0$ for $n,m > M$ for some $M$.  If only $|a_n - a_{n+1}|\rightarrow 0$ that is only the difference of *adjacent* terms.  It does not imply Cauchy.

Obviously if all $n,m > M$ are such that $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$ then for all $n > M$ then $|a_n-a_m| < \epsilon$ and $n+1 > M$.  But the converse isn't necessarily true.  That something is true for all $n, n+1 > M$ in no way should it be true for all $n,m > M$.